# Show that it is a element of $(H^1(\Omega))'$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $\Omega$ a open regular subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 1$.

I want to prove that if $u\in L^2(\Omega)$, the distribution $\partial_{x_i} u $ is an element of $(H^1(\Omega))'$ (for $1\le i \le n$).

I totally understand the proof when we replace $(H^1(\Omega))'$ by $H^{-1} = (H^1_0(\Omega))'$, but for the proof of $H^{-1}$ we crucially use the definition of the derivative of a distribution, to say that
$$ 
< \partial_{x_i} u , \varphi > = - <u, \partial_{x_i} \varphi>
$$
for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\Omega)$ and then we extend the linear form. But here, we want to take $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$, so how what is the first step? (a reference and/or a complete proof will be perfect)

Comment: The distribution $\partial_{x_i} u$ defines a continuous linear functional on $H_0^1$, which is a closed subspace of $H^1$. By Hahn-Banach, it admits an extension to a continuous linear functional on $H^1$. Perhaps this is unsatisfactory, because one expects to a *canonical* functional on $H^1$, with which to identify the distribution. But I am not convinced that there is a natural identification of this kind.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice Your comment is very interesting. If you post it as answer, I would be happy to up-vote it and accept it as an answer.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice In fact, do we really need that $H^1_0$ is a closed subspace of $H^1$? The fact that is a vectorial subspace is sufficient, no?

Comment: Yes, I put *closed* there just because it is. Not needed.